# How do I set up XAMPP to allow me to download plugins and themes?

Tags: plugins, themes, xampp

It's been a very long time since I used Wordpress and I am getting back into it. I have installed XAMPP on my Mac (10.14.2) and have successfully installed Wordpress 5.1.1.

However, I cannot figure out how to set things up so I can download and install plugins.

Would anyone know how or know of a good guide to set up XAMPP and Wordpress so I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

A common issue related to this is that XAMPP can't write to your `wp-content` directory.

If you don't know how to change this, you can edit `wp-config.php` and add this line:

`define('FS_METHOD','direct');`

For detailed information, read [wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) documentation.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer! Could you [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/332059/edit) and add in a bit more detail regarding what this flag is, what it does, and why it would help solve the original issue?